# Find all incongruent primitive roots of a number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to find all incongruent primitive roots of $14$. I know that there are $\phi{(\phi{(14)})}=2$ incongruent primitives roots, where I have found that both $3$ and $5$ are primitive roots mod $14$.

My question is: why aren't $11$ and $13$ also primitive roots mod 14? Both $11^6 \equiv 13^6 \equiv 1$ mod $14$, by Euler's Theorem. So why are there only $2$ incongruent solutions mod $14$.

Comment: Ohhh, I see. Thank you!

Comment: Or simply: just because you proved there are only two, which are 3 and 5. So, your question can be considered as a duplicate of [Show that 3 is a primitive root modulo 14. Then, write the other primitive roots modulo 14 in terms of powers of 3. How many are there?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1745477/show-that-3-is-a-primitive-root-modulo-14-then-write-the-other-primitive-roots)

Comment: $   11 \equiv -3 \pmod{14}$  Its string of powers starts $-3, 9, -27$   But $   -27 \equiv 1 \pmod{14}$